# String Encoding issue - PHP

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I need to store the column name from csv file into mysql DB, In PHP i have used to convert the string to utf8_encode format. it does not work for some string,

```
$name = "Téléphone"
echo utf8_encode($name); // it works

output : Téléphone

$name = "Etat œuvre"
echo utf8_encode($name); // it does not works

output : Etat Å?uvre
```

For testing:

```
echo bin2hex($name);
output: 45746174209c75767265
```

Comment: `utf8_encode` is a very useless function. It definitely does not do what you would think it does.

Comment: `utf8_encode` converts from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8. The character "œ" does not exist in ISO-8859-1, so it's rather unclear how it exists in the first place. How is your source code encoded? If in doubt, do `echo bin2hex('Etat œuvre')`.

Comment: Start by answering my above question.

Comment: @deceze it prints 45746174209c75767265

Answer (score 1):

> 45746174209c75767265

The "œ" in here is `9c`, which points to the string being encoded in [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). `utf8_encode` converts from [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) to UTF-8, so you're doing the wrong encoding conversion. The correct one is:

```
mb_convert_encoding('Etat œuvre', 'UTF-8', 'CP1252')
```

Comment: above code work correctly in linux machine (code deployed in linux machine), not in windows machine.

Answer (score -1):

`utf8_encode` is not the "right tool" for this task. Try `mb_convert_encoding` instead.

Example:

```php
function encodeUtf8(string $data): string
{
    if (!mb_check_encoding($data, 'UTF-8')) {
        return mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8');
    }

    return $data;
}

echo encodeUtf8('Téléphone'); // Téléphone
echo encodeUtf8('Etat œuvre'); // Etat œuvre
```

Comment: Encoding conversion should not involve any `if` statements. If you don't know what encoding you're converting *from*, then you better not convert at all.

Comment: @deceze If the content is already UTF-8 encoded, then it is not necessary to encode it twice.

Comment: If you knew that the content was already UTF-8 encoded, you wouldn't need to call this function in the first place. Again, you must *know* what you're converting from, not let the code decide.

Comment: @deceze I don't share your opinion, because in real life that's not always possible.

Comment: Any code that you write has full control over what encodings you use. Any interface between two systems has metadata ways to annotate what encoding is being used (e.g. HTTP headers, meta tags, database connection encoding settings etc.). The only time you absolutely don't know is when you accept arbitrary plaintext files. And here the strategy must be to 1) ask the user for the encoding and/or 2) try to check for a few commonly used encodings and have the user confirm using a preview. Relying on the undefined `$from_encoding` parameter of `mb_convert_encoding` isn't sane.